# MySQL - SELECT from one table COUNT from 2 others

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables: `Users`, `Friends`, `Movies` and `User_Movies`.

`Users` and `Movies` are just a list of users and movies.

`Friends` has just 2 columns: *`#fan_id`, `#idol_id`* and is there only to say "user 1 follows user 2".

`User_Movies` has 2 columns: *`#user_id`, `#movie_id`* and is there to say "user has movie".

Ok. Now I want to SELECT every users, a COUNT of his friends and his movies. I've started to get the number of friends, but I don't know how to get the number of movies too. Can anyone help please ?

```
SELECT u.`id`, u.`username`, COUNT(*) AS n_relation
FROM `users` u
JOIN `friends` f ON f.`idol_id` = u.`id`
OR f.`fan_id` = u.`id`
WHERE `username` = ?
GROUP BY u.`id`;`
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  u.*,
  (select count(*) from friends f where f.idol_id = u.id) as fancount,
  (select count(*) from user_movies m where m.user_id = u.id) as moviecount
from
  users u
where 
  u.username = 'j.doe'
```

Alternative, that *may* be faster (but you should test whether that is the case in your database):

```
select
  u.*,
  uf.fancount,
  um.moviecount
from
  users u
  left join 
    (select 
      f.idol_id, count(*) as fancount 
    from friends f) uf on uf.idol_id = u.id
  left join
    (select 
      m.user_id, count(*) as moviecount 
    from user_movies m) um on um.user_id = u.id
where 
  u.username = 'j.doe'
```

A third option, that looks like your attempt and that of desimusxvii, only it uses `distinct` which 'fixes' the count issue, where movies are counted multiple times when you got more than one friend and vice versa. 
I would advise against this option, though, because the query is less readable and maintainable. It abuses `group by` while it should not be needed.

```
select
  u.username,
  count(distinct f.fan_id) as fancount,
  count(distinct m.movie_id) as moviecount
from
  users u
  left join friends f on f.idol_id = u.user_id
  left join user_movies m on m.user_id = u.user_id
where 
  u.username = 'j.doe'
group by 
  u.username
```

Comment: Thank you. Perfect. But finally after tests, subselects are faster :/ But iit helped, thanks.